# How to study relation and functions?

Tags: functions, reference-request, self-learning, relations, book-recommendation

I was interested in abstract algebra but the book I took up suggested I learn a bit of linear algebra, So I tried another book for it and then it went on and assumed I had knowledge of calculus, and continuing on this cycle I settled down that the base that would be starting this could possibly be Relation and Function(the one that is injective/bijective/surjective{is this true?}).
   What would be the best resource to study this and study this to an advanced level? I tried my go searching through the web and there are ample resources but all scattered, so I was in hoping to find a good book but I don't even know which branch of mathematics holds this particular topic. Please advice me a good resource for this.

Comment: I believe this would be in the topic sets and relations

Comment: I don't think you really need a rigorous idea of sets and relations to start studying calculus or abstract algebra.  You can get a feel for them in [Stitz and Zeager's Precalculus](http://www.stitz-zeager.com/) (Chapter 1).  If you're insistent that you'd like to learn actual set theory (the branch of math dealing with sets, relations, and functions among other things) before taking on abstract algebra, I recommend starting with [Hrbacek and Jech's book](https://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Revised-Expanded-Chapman-Mathematics/dp/0824779150).

Comment: @BobbieD, Thanks. Any suggestions for beginner's abstract algebra. I found Thomas W. Judson's book, (don't know if it's beginner's though) and includes a strange notation for matrices that I did not understand, if you can, please give me a suggestion for that as well.

Comment: @BeshalJaenal My intro abstract algebra book was *Algebra* by Michael Artin.  I thought it was pretty good, especially on group theory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a great (and free) resource you can use. Part four is all about relations, functions, and cardinality and there are plenty of practice problems to help cement your knowledge:

http://www.people.vcu.edu/~rhammack/BookOfProof/

It's a good book for laying a foundation and then moving on to more advanced topics in theoretical mathematics. It does not assume prior calculus knowledge but you may need to look a few things up as you go through it. Also, feel free to jump to relations and functions but I think starting at the beginning and working through will pay massive dividends for any theoretical math course you take down the line.

The great thing is, this book is more of an overview on methods of proof and notation that you will see in courses such as abstract algebra. The idea here is that you get broad exposure and an array of new perspectives on old ideas that you  have learned over the years... basically it helps you cross over from surface level mathematical thinking, to a deeper, richer understanding.

Comment: Excellent suggestion. Was about to suggest it myself if it wasn't already here.

Comment: If it weren't for the community, I would never know how. Thanks !!